# buckyroberts ReactJS Example - strange behavior

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to extend buckyrobert's reactjs example.  And I ran into two issues:

1. How can I write a "toggle all" function to put all components into edit mode?
2. This looks like a flat out bug.
   a. Run the below.
   b. Add three new components.
   c. Edit the middle one (i.e., #2) and enter "2".
   d. Click Save, and Click Edit on the middle one again.
   e. Remove the first component.

See the issue.

~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React - Template</title>
    <script src="../../js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function () {
                console.log("initial: " + this.props.index + ":" + this.props.editing);
                return {editing: this.props.toggleFlag}
            },

            edit: function() {
                console.log("editing ");
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },

            save: function() {
                var val = this.refs.newText.value;
                console.log("save: " + val);
                this.props.saveComment(this.props.index, val);
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },

            remove: function() {
                console.log("removing ");
                this.props.removeComment(this.props.index);
            },

            cancel: function() {
                console.log("cancel");
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },

            renderForm: function() {
                return (
                        <div className="commentContainer">
                            <textarea ref="newText" className="commentText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                            <button onClick={this.save} className="button-primary">Save</button>
                            <button onClick={this.cancel} className="button-danger">Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                )
            },

            renderNormal: function() {
               return (
                   <div className="commentContainer">
                       <div ref="newText" className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
                       <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
                       <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
                   </div>
               )
            },

            render: function () {
                if (this.state.editing) {
                    return this.renderForm();
                } else {
                    return this.renderNormal();
                }
            }
        });

        var Board = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function () {
                return {
                    toggleFlag: false,
                    comments: [
                    ]
                }
            },

            add: function (text) {
                console.log(typeof(text));
                if (typeof(text) != "string") {
                    text = "";
                }
                console.log("add: " + text);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr.push(text);
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            remove: function(i) {
                console.log("removing: " + i);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr.splice(i, 1);
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            save: function(i, newText) {
                console.log("saving: " + i);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr[i] = newText;
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            toggle: function () {
                var newToggle = !this.state.toggleFlag;
                this.setState({toggleFlag: newToggle});
                console.log(newToggle);
            },

            eachComment: function (text, i) {
                console.log("each: " + i + ":" + this.state.toggleFlag);
                return (
                    <Comment key={i} index={i} saveComment={this.save} removeComment={this.remove} toggleFlag={this.state.toggleFlag}>{text}</Comment>
                )
            },

            render: function () {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <button className="button-info create" onClick={this.add}>Add New</button>
                        <button className="button-info" onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle Edit</button>
                        <div className="board">
                            {
                                this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Board/>,
            document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React - Template</title>
    <script src="../../js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function () {
                console.log("initial: " + this.props.index + ":" + this.props.editing);
                return {editing: this.props.toggleFlag}
            },

            edit: function() {
                console.log("editing ");
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },

            save: function() {
                var val = this.refs.newText.value;
                console.log("save: " + val);
                this.props.saveComment(this.props.index, val);
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },

            remove: function() {
                console.log("removing ");
                this.props.removeComment(this.props.index);
            },

            cancel: function() {
                console.log("cancel");
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },

            renderForm: function() {
                return (
                        <div className="commentContainer">
                            <textarea ref="newText" className="commentText" defaultValue={this.props.children}></textarea>
                            <button onClick={this.save} className="button-primary">Save</button>
                            <button onClick={this.cancel} className="button-danger">Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                )
            },

            renderNormal: function() {
               return (
                   <div className="commentContainer">
                       <div ref="newText" className="commentText">{this.props.children}</div>
                       <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
                       <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove</button>
                   </div>
               )
            },

            render: function () {
                if (this.state.editing) {
                    return this.renderForm();
                } else {
                    return this.renderNormal();
                }
            }
        });

        var Board = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function () {
                return {
                    toggleFlag: false,
                    comments: [
                    ]
                }
            },

            add: function (text) {
                console.log(typeof(text));
                if (typeof(text) != "string") {
                    text = "";
                }
                console.log("add: " + text);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr.push(text);
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            remove: function(i) {
                console.log("removing: " + i);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr.splice(i, 1);
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            save: function(i, newText) {
                console.log("saving: " + i);
                var arr = this.state.comments;
                arr[i] = newText;
                this.setState({comments: arr});
            },

            toggle: function () {
                var newToggle = !this.state.toggleFlag;
                this.setState({toggleFlag: newToggle});
                console.log(newToggle);
            },

            eachComment: function (text, i) {
                console.log("each: " + i + ":" + this.state.toggleFlag);
                return (
                    <Comment key={i} index={i} saveComment={this.save} removeComment={this.remove} toggleFlag={this.state.toggleFlag}>{text}</Comment>
                )
            },

            render: function () {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <button className="button-info create" onClick={this.add}>Add New</button>
                        <button className="button-info" onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle Edit</button>
                        <div className="board">
                            {
                                this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Board/>,
            document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried running your code. I'm not sure if we both see the exact same behavior based on your code but here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ickyrr/qtyj1jyy/). I followed your instructions on how to replicate the issue, did not see any wierd behavior. Can you instead describe what that bug is?

Comment: See https://youtu.be/W8UU49X7vMg

Comment: Any updates on what is wrong?  The video above should demonstrate the issue.